# Angular Pass Request Body to a Restful Interface

Tags: angularjs, rest

My restful controller is receiving a null Request Body from an angular POST and I'm not sure why.

Here's the code for my controller:

```
adminController.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'Profile', 'AvailableProfiles',
        function ($scope, $modal, $log, Profile, AvailableProfiles) {
    $scope.open = function (uuid, profile) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {
                profile: function () {
                    return profile;
                },
                AvailableProfiles: function () {
                    return AvailableProfiles;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            Profile.save({uuid: uuid}, {profile: profile});
        }, function () {});
    };
}]);
```

And here's the code for my service:

```
adminService.factory('Profile', ['$resource',
    function($resource, uuid, profile) {
        return $resource(baseUrl + 'candidate/:uuid/profile', {profile}, {
            save: {method: 'POST', params: {uuid: uuid}},
        });
    }
]);
```

Any thoughts on why this profile object isn't being passed into the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call save on the profile object.

```
modalInstance.result.then(function () {
    profile.$save({uuid: uuid});
}, function () {});
```